# Fetching data from JSON file

Tags: jquery, json

I have a JSON file which I call using jQuery. I have used a jQuery UI-slider which takes a min and max price. When I click on the submit button it should display all the names of the hotels which lies in that range. Here is my code:

```
var params = {
  checkIn: '20160505',
  checkOut: '20160509',
  location: 'mco'
}

$('#submitform').on('click', function() {
  var min_price = $('#slider').slider("values", 0);
  var max_price = $('#slider').slider("values", 1);
  alert(min_price);
  alert(max_price);
  var urlBase = 'api/data.json';

  $.get(urlBase, params)
    .done(function(hotels) {
      //  $.get(urlBase, params)
      //        .done( function( hotels ) {
      var table = document.createElement("table");
      $('#data').append(table)
      for (var i = min_price; i <= hotels.length; i++) {
        for (var j = max_price; j <= hotels.length; j--) {
          var tr = document.createElement("tr");
          var nametd = document.createElement("td");
          nametd.innerHTML = hotels[i].name
          var pricetd = document.createElement("td");
          pricetd.innerHTML = hotels[i].ratesSummary.minPrice
          var ratingtd = document.createElement("td")
          ratingtd.innerHTML = hotels[i].starRating
          var guesttd = document.createElement("td")
          guesttd.innerHTML = hotels[i].overallGuestRating
          table.appendChild(tr)
          tr.appendChild(nametd);
          tr.appendChild(pricetd);
          tr.appendChild(ratingtd);
          tr.appendChild(guesttd);
        }
      }
      $('#data').append(table)
    });
});

$(function() {
  $("#slider").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 35,
    max: 165
  });
});
```

Comment: `$('#submitform').on('click' ...)` should be inside `$(function() { ... })`

Comment: Is `#submitForm` the submit button for a form? If it is, you need to disable the default form submission with `event.preventDefault()`.

Comment: i tried its still not working

Comment: no its just a name its inside a div tag

Comment: Are you seeing the alerts?

Comment: yes I am seeing them

Comment: So what is the problem you're having? I just noticed that your inner loop never uses `j`, what is the loop for?

Comment: Are the array indexes really the same as the prices? That's what your loop seems to assume.

Comment: I have a json file and a jquery file. In the jquery file I have a slider for price option that user could select
For ex: if user selects price range between 50 to 100$, on clicking submit the user should be able to see the options between the price range.
Well on clicking submit the submit button wont direct and extract the data from the json file

the loop is to fetch the data from the json file.
I just need the code to be inserted on submit button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your loops to:

```
for (var i = 0; i < hotels.length; i++) {
    if (hotels[i].price < min_price || hotels[i].price > max_price) {
        continue; // skip hotel out of price range
    }
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    ...
}
```

Your code was using the array indexes as the price, and using a nested loops for no reason.

Comment: I get the json file now, but it fetches everything  and not just the value user asks for